# What problems does reflection solve?

Tags: c#, reflection

I went through all the posts on [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_metadata#Reflection) but couldn't find the answer to my question.

What were the problems in the programming world before .NET reflection
came and how it solved those problems?

Please explain with an example.

Comment: @Praveen - this is a pretty broad question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Currently Not a Real Question: impossible to answer. Perhaps if you expanded with what you are trying to determine.

Comment: Isn't this question equivalent as "What problems does reflection solve?" ... yes, this sounds a lot like a homework/exam type of question.

Comment: It's poorly worded, but perfectly normal question. It's like you interview someone on COM and he starts rambling how IUnknown AddRef() and Release() work abut you would rather hear what the problem is that reference counting is used in the first place.

Comment: Perfectly legit question. Why we need something is as important and as much about programming as what it does and how it does it.

Comment: "What problems does Reflection create?"  Answer this question for bonus marks.

Comment: It helps when not everything is known in advance. Also when some logic is to be expressed outside the source, but still relates to that (attributes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be stated that .NET reflection isn't revolutionary - the concepts have been around in other framework.

Reflection in .NET has 2 facets:

**Investigating type information**

Without some kind of reflection / introspection API, it becomes very hard to perform things like serialization. Rather than having this provided at runtime (by inspecting the properties/fields/etc), you often need code-generation instead, i.e. code that explicitly knows how to serialize each of your types. Tedious, and painful if you want to serialize something that doesn't have a twin.

Likewise, there is nowhere to store additional metadata about properties etc, so you end up having lots of additional code, or external configuration files. Something as simple as being able to associate a friendly name with a property (via an attribute) is a huge win for UI code.

**Metaprogramming**

.NET reflection also provides a mechanism to create types (etc) at runtime, which is hugely powerful for some specific scenarios; the alternatives are:

- essentially running a parser/logic tree at runtime (rather than compiling the logic at runtime into executable code) - much slower
- yet more code generation - yay!

Answer (score 9):

I think to understand the need for reflection in .NET, we need to go back to before .NET.  After all, modern languages like like Java and C# do not have a history BF (before reflection).

C++ arguably has had the most influence on C# and Java.  But C++ did not originally have reflection and we coded without it and we managed to get by.  Occasionally we had void pointer and would use a cast to force it into whatever type we wanted.  The problem here was that the cast could fail with terrible consequences:

```
double CalculateSize(void* rectangle) {
    return ((Rect*)rectangle)->getWidth() * ((Rect*)rectangle)->getHeight());
}
```

Now there are plenty of arguments why you shouldn't have coded yourself into this problem in the first place.  But the problem is not much different from .NET 1.1 with C# when we didn't have generics:

```
Hashtable shapes = new Hashtable();
....
double CalculateSize(object shape) {
    return ((Rect)shape).Width * ((Rect)shape).Height;
}
```

However, when the C# example fails it does so with a exception rather than a potential core dump.

When reflection was added to C++ (known as Run Time Type Identification or RTTI), it was hotly debated.  In Stroustrup's book The Design and Evolution of C++, he lists the following 
arguments against RTTI, in that some people:

> ```
> Declared the support unnecessary
> Declared the new style inherently evil ("against the spirit of C++")
> Deemed it too expensive
> Thought it too complicated and confusing
> Saw it as the beginning of an avalanche of new features
> ```

But it did allow us to query the type of objects, or features of objects.  For example (using C#)

```
Hashtable shapes = new Hashtable();
....
double CalculateSize(object shape) {
    if(shape is Rect) {
        return ((Rect)shape).Width * ((Rect)shape).Height;
    }
    else if(shape is Circle) {
        return Math.Power(((Circle)shape).Radius, 2.0) * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

Of course, with proper planning this example should never need to occur.

So, real world situations where I've needed it include:

- Accessing objects from shared memory, all I have is a pointer and I need to decide what to do with it.
- Dynamically loading assemblies, think about NUnit where it loads every assembly and uses reflection to determine which classes are test fixtures.
- Having a mixed bag of objects in a Hashtable and wanting to process them differently in an enumerator.
- Many others...

So, I would go as far as to argue that Reflection has not enabled the ability to do something that couldn't be done before.  However, it does make some types of problems easier to code, clearer to reader, shorter to write, etc.

Of course that's just my opinion, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I once wanted to have unit tests in a text file that could be modified by a non-technical user in the format in C++:

```
MyObj Function args //textfile.txt
```

But I couldn't find a way to read in a string and then have the code create an object instance of the type represented by the string without reflection which C++ doesn't support.

```
char *str; //read in some type from a text file say the string is "MyObj"
str *obj;  //cast a pointer as type MyObj  
obj = new str;  //create a MyObj
```

Another use might be to have a generic copy function that could copy the members of an class without knowing them in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It helps a lot when you are using C# attributes like [Obsolete] or [Serializable] in your code. Frameworks like [NUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) use reflection on classes and containing methods to understand which methods are tests, setup, teardown, etc.